# Grouping overlapping points by UTC Time, sum and average?

Tags: qgis, grouping

I have data from airplane calibrations where the plane flies in a crossing pattern; i.e. going E->W and W->E, then N->S and S->N.

I need to sum and average the values for both flights in each direction (i.e. when the plane goes E->W, and then W->E) and get the absolute difference.

I'm able to assign 'NS' or 'EW' using SAGA's [Separate Points By Direction](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.2.2/shapes_points_9.html) algorithm and then using a field calculator. However, I don't know how to differentiate the E->W flight from the W->E flight. Any ideas?

The only idea I have is that there is a UTCTime attribute; so we can group EW data into two separate groups by time somehow, but the flights are always at different hours of the day on successive surveys.

I'd like to be able to do this using a graphical modeller so no 3rd party plugins if possible.